# How do I make bluefish open only one instance?

Tags: fedora-17, bluefish

When opening files in blue fish, by default it keeps opens new files in new windows rather than opening one instance and then opening several tabs.

OS: `Fedora 17`

Bluefish version: `2.2.3`

How can I open new files in the existing bluefish window?

Answer (score 2):

In Bluefish, you can set this via properties:

```
Preferences --> Files
```

Check "Open commandline files in running bluefish process"

Uncheck "Open commandline files in new window"